# ServiceLeakedException while using services android

Tags: android

I had a Activity That is binding with a service and is able to communicate with  the service as well.

```
 bindService(intent,serviceConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

My Code is running well. But when i finishes my activity A ServiceLeakedException is thrown, but that is there in the log only. no such exception is their on to the visuals and is working fine.

Should i ignore this or how to handle this properly.

Thanks 
Amandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats easy to trick down.

You are forgetting to unbind from the service.

Just override the onDestroy delegate of your Activity and in that unbind from the service.
Do something like this

```
 protected void onDestroy()
  {
     unbind(serviceConnection);
     super.onDestroy()
  }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you for your reply. i will let  you know the result.. let me try this out